# Health checks failed with these codes: [502] - Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs, aws-application-load-balancer

Hi I am using cloudforamtion to create ecs cluster, service and task. In task I am simply pulling wordpress image and connecting it to rds database. The problem here is the instance in the target group goes to `draining` state and then turn unhealthy. Wordpress shows up in the dns of alb but when you refresh it sometime gives error `502 bad gateway`. I am only attaching the template where the error can exist most probably I might be giving the port wrong. I have good connection to the database (I have checked it as I did ssh into the instance and then used `mysql -umysqldb -pmysql123a -h rds.endpoint` command). The targets in targetgroup shoes an error `Health checks failed with these codes: [502]`

Task:

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09 
Parameters:
    ExRole:
      Type: String
    RDS:
      Type: String
Resources:
    Task:
        Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
        Properties:
            Family: wordpress 
            Cpu: 1 vCPU
            ExecutionRoleArn: !Ref ExRole
            Memory: 1 GB
            NetworkMode: bridge
            RequiresCompatibilities:
                - EC2
            TaskRoleArn: !Ref ExRole
            ContainerDefinitions: 
              - Essential: true
                Image: wordpress:latest
                Name: wordpress
                PortMappings:  
                  - ContainerPort: 80
                    HostPort: 0
                    Protocol: tcp 
                Environment:
                  - Name: WORDPRESS_DB_HOST
                    Value: !Ref RDS 
                  - Name: WORDPRESS_DB_USER
                    Value: mysqldb 
                  - Name: WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD
                    Value: mysql123a 
                  - Name: WORDPRESS_DB_NAME
                    Value: mysqldb 
    
Outputs:
  Task:
    Description: Contains all the task specifications
    Value: !Ref Task
    Export:
      Name: "Task"
```

alb:

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Parameters:
    SubnetA:
      Type: String
    SubnetB:
      Type: String
    VpcID:
      Type: String
Resources:
    Albsg:
        Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
        Properties:
            GroupName: alb-sg
            VpcId: !Ref VpcID
            SecurityGroupIngress:
                - IpProtocol: tcp
                  FromPort: 80
                  ToPort: 80
                  CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
                  Description: For traffic from Internet
            GroupDescription: Security Group for demo server
    Alb:
        Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
        Properties: 
            IpAddressType: ipv4
            Name: Alb
            Scheme: internet-facing
            SecurityGroups: 
                - !Ref Albsg
            Subnets:
                - Ref: "SubnetA"
                - Ref: "SubnetB"
            Type: application
    DefaultTargetGroup:
        Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
        DependsOn: Alb
        Properties:
            Name: alb-tg
            VpcId: !Ref VpcID
            Port: 80
            Protocol: HTTP
    LoadBalancerListener:
        Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
        Properties:
            LoadBalancerArn: !Ref Alb
            Port: 80
            Protocol: HTTP
            DefaultActions:
                - Type: forward
                  TargetGroupArn: !Ref DefaultTargetGroup
Outputs:
  Albsg:
    Description: security group for application load balancer
    Value: !Ref Albsg
    Export:
        Name: "Albsg"
  Alb:
    Description: application load balancer
    Value: !Ref Alb
    Export:
      Name: "Alb"
  DefaultTargetGroup:
    Description: Default Target Group
    Value: !Ref DefaultTargetGroup
    Export:
      Name: "DefaultTargetGroup"
```

Cluster and service

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09

Parameters:

  KeyName:
    Type: AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName
    Default: webserver

  DesiredCapacity:
    Type: Number
    Default: 2

  MinSize:
    Type: Number
    Default: 1

  MaxSize:
    Type: Number
    Default: 4  

  InstanceProfile:
    Type: String

  DefaultTargetGroup:
    Type: String
  
  Task:
    Type: String

  Albsg:
    Type: String

  VpcID:
    Type: String

  SubnetA:
    Type: String
      
  SubnetB:
    Type: String
  
  webserver:
    Type: String


Resources:

  MyCluster:
      Type: AWS::ECS::Cluster
      Properties: {}

  Myservice:
      Type: AWS::ECS::Service
      Properties: 
          Cluster: !Ref MyCluster        
          DeploymentController:   
              Type: ECS
          DesiredCount: 2
          LaunchType: EC2
          LoadBalancers: 
              - ContainerName: wordpress
                ContainerPort: 80
                TargetGroupArn: !Ref DefaultTargetGroup
          #Role: !Ref InstanceProfile
          SchedulingStrategy: REPLICA
          ServiceName: wordpress
          TaskDefinition: !Ref Task

  ec2instance:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration
    Properties:
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64: !Sub |
          #!/bin/bash -xe

          yum update -y && yum install -y aws-cfn-bootstrap 

          echo ECS_CLUSTER=${MyCluster} >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
          echo ECS_BACKEND_HOST= >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config           

          /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? \
                --stack ${AWS::StackName} \
                --resource myASG \
                --region ${AWS::Region}

      BlockDeviceMappings:
        - DeviceName: /dev/xvda
          Ebs:
            DeleteOnTermination: "true"
            VolumeSize: 30
            VolumeType: gp2
      ImageId: ami-06e05a843071324d1 
      InstanceType: t2.small
      IamInstanceProfile: !Ref InstanceProfile
      KeyName: !Ref KeyName
      SecurityGroups:
          - Ref: webserver

  myASG:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
    CreationPolicy:
      ResourceSignal:
        Timeout: PT5M
        Count: !Ref DesiredCapacity
    Properties:
      #AutoScalingGroupName: myASG
      MinSize: !Ref MinSize
      MaxSize: !Ref MaxSize
      DesiredCapacity: !Ref DesiredCapacity
      HealthCheckGracePeriod: 300
      LaunchConfigurationName:
        Ref: ec2instance
      VPCZoneIdentifier:
        - !Ref SubnetA
        - !Ref SubnetB
      TargetGroupARNs:
        - !Ref DefaultTargetGroup
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> most probably I might be giving the port wrong

In your `Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition` you have defined **port 80** for the wordpress.

But your target group is using **port 8080**:

```
       Properties:
            Name: alb-tg
            VpcId: !Ref VpcID
            Port: 8080 # <--- should be 80
            Protocol: HTTP
```

To use 302 code for health checks:

```
    DefaultTargetGroup:
        Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
        DependsOn: Alb
        Properties:
            Name: alb-tg
            VpcId: !Ref VpcID
            Port: 80
            Protocol: HTTP
            Matcher: 
              HttpCode: 302
```

Comment: what changes should I make if I want to deploy the same stack in prod and qa environment? The stack that I have now have a conflict in names.

Comment: @aws-noob Hi. Not sure. You would have to provide some examples of the new error messages. As this seems as a new issue, you could consider making new question as well.

Comment: Marcin now it is showing `Health checks failed with these codes: [302]` :|

Comment: @aws-noob  302 is redirection code. Probably your health check returns 302 instead of 200. You can modify the expected code using [Matcher](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-elasticloadbalancingv2-targetgroup-matcher.html).

Comment: @aws-noob No. The matcher should be set to 302: `HttpCode: 302`. I will udpate the answer.